# Spill formula to lookup different sections of table based on two arguments

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I have a table of data that I need to do a lookup on (exact match or next smaller item), but the lookup needs to only look at a small section of the table based on the *Vendor* and *Source* columns.

The table is the result of PowerQuery and is called *GroupedData*.  It's sorted by Vendor, Source and Days.

What I would like to do is:

- For each combination of Vendor/Source I calculate the total Count of Orders.
- Calculate 95% of the totals.
- Lookup which day that 95% value was reached (i.e. look up on the Running Total column and return from the Days column).

For example:

- The total for *V1/SA* is 102.
- 95% of 102 is 96.9.
- The lookup will return 4 days as Count of Orders = 11+52=63 is less than the 95%, while 11+52+35=98 is more.

I'd be happy with either a formula or power query answer if possible.

| Vendor | Source | Days | Count of Orders | Running Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| V1 | SA | 3 | 11 | 11 |
| V1 | SA | 4 | 52 | 63 |
| V1 | SA | 5 | 35 | 98 |
| V1 | SA | 6 | 3 | 101 |
| V1 | SA | 7 | 1 | 102 |
| V1 | SB | 2 | 10 | 10 |
| V1 | SB | 3 | 15 | 25 |
| V1 | SB | 5 | 100 | 125 |
| V1 | SB | 6 | 3 | 128 |
| V1 | SB | 7 | 2 | 130 |
| V2 | SA | 8 | 1 | 131 |
| V2 | SA | 9 | 1 | 132 |
| V2 | SB | 5 | 428 | 428 |
| V2 | SB | 6 | 5,226 | 5,654 |
| V2 | SB | 7 | 15,800 | 21,454 |
| V2 | SB | 8 | 13,713 | 35,167 |
| V2 | SB | 10 | 8,529 | 43,696 |
| V2 | SC | 2 | 3,618 | 3,618 |
| V2 | SC | 3 | 2,856 | 6,474 |
| V2 | SC | 4 | 941 | 7,415 |
| V2 | SD | 1 | 669 | 669 |
| V2 | SD | 2 | 520 | 1,189 |
| V2 | SD | 3 | 392 | 1,581 |

My results table at the moment looks like this:
[image: Results Table]

The formula used in results so far:

- *H2*  `=UNIQUE(GroupedData[[Vendor]:[Source]])`
- *J2*  `=MAXIFS(GroupedData[Days],GroupedData[Vendor],INDEX($H$2#,,1),GroupedData[Source],INDEX($H$2#,,2))`
- *K2* `=SUMIFS(GroupedData[Count of Orders],GroupedData[Vendor],INDEX($H$2#,,1),GroupedData[Source],INDEX($H$2#,,2))`
- *M2* `=K2#*95%`

Formula I've tried:

Returns #VALUE! for each value

```
=LET(LookupArray,XLOOKUP(INDEX($O$4#,,1) & INDEX($O$4#,,2),GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Running Total],,-1):XLOOKUP(INDEX($O$4#,,1) & INDEX($O$4#,,2),GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Running Total],,-1,-1),
     ReturnArray, XLOOKUP(INDEX($O$4#,,1) & INDEX($O$4#,,2),GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Days],,-1):XLOOKUP(INDEX($O$4#,,1) & INDEX($O$4#,,2),GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Days],,-1,-1),
     Result, XLOOKUP($T$4#,LookupArray,ReturnArray),
     Result)
```

Returns a single #CALC! error:

```
=BYROW(O4#,
       LAMBDA(MyArray,
              LET(LookupArray,XLOOKUP(INDEX(MyArray,,1) & INDEX(MyArray,,2),GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Running Total],,-1):XLOOKUP(INDEX(MyArray,,1) & INDEX(MyArray,,2),GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Running Total],,-1,-1), 
                  ReturnArray, XLOOKUP(INDEX(MyArray,,1) & INDEX(MyArray,,2),GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Days],,-1):XLOOKUP(INDEX(MyArray,,1) & INDEX(MyArray,,2),GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Days],,-1,-1), 
                  Result, XLOOKUP($T$4#,LookupArray,ReturnArray,,-1), 
                  Result)))
```

Bit of waffle that may be relevant:
`=XLOOKUP(INDEX(H2#,,1) & INDEX(H2#,,2),GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Running Total],,-1)` returns all the first values in the Running Total.  Using a *Search Last to First* parameter returns all the last values for each group.

`=XLOOKUP(H2 & I2,GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Running Total],,-1):XLOOKUP(H2 & I2,GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Running Total],,-1,-1)` returns all the Running Totals for the first group.

`=XLOOKUP($M$2,XLOOKUP(H2 & I2,GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Running Total],,-1):XLOOKUP(H2 & I2,GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Running Total],,-1,-1),XLOOKUP(H2 & I2,GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Days],,-1):XLOOKUP(H2 & I2,GroupedData[Vendor] & GroupedData[Source],GroupedData[Days],,-1,-1),,-1)` works for a single group, but I'd need to drag down rather than let it spill.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your running totals don't appear to be working properly - they didn't reset for V2 and SA for example. Otherwise you could use something like MAP: `=MAP(INDEX(H2#,,1),INDEX(H2#,,2),L2#,LAMBDA(a,b,c,LOOKUP(2,1/(GroupedData[Vendor]=a)/(GroupedData[Source]=b)/(GroupedData[Running Total]<=c),GroupedData[Days])))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Rory - that running total error is me.  I manually made the example so hopefully that's where the error is and not on my actual data.  I knew it would be the `MAP` function, I'm just not very good with it  yet.  I'll have to check in the morning now - meant to have left the office 10 minutes ago. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powerquery this pulls the highest Running Total up until 95% of the total volume

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Vendor", "Source"}, {{"data", each _, type table}, {"All", each List.Max([Days]), type number}, {"Volume", each List.Sum([Count of Orders]), type number}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "95% Vol", each .95*[Volume]),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "95%",(x)=>List.Last(Table.SelectRows(x[data], each [Running Total] <= x[Volume]*.95)[Running Total])),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"data"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @horseyride.  That worked, I just had to update `[Running Total]` in `#"Added Custom2"` to `[Days]` so it returned the corresponding day count rather than the Running Total value.  I'll accept this one as it's the solution I've used, but want to check the formula as well so I can upvote if they work.

Answer (score 0):

`=MAP(H2:H7&"|"&I2:I7,K2:K7,LAMBDA(vs,rt,XLOOKUP(rt*0.95,rt*(Table1[Vendor]&"|"&Table1[Source]=vs),Table1[Days],,1)))`

Where `H2:H7` and `I2:I7` are from your results table and are combined into an array and mapped as `vs` and `K2:K7` the Volume (max of Running Total) is mapped as `rt`.
These are used inside XLOOKUP to return the days from your table when your running total first reached 95% of the max value.

Or using references as mentioned in your post:
`=MAP(TAKE(H2#,,1)&"|"&DROP(H2#,,1),K2#,LAMBDA(vs,rt,XLOOKUP(rt*0.95,rt*(GroupedData[Vendor]&"|"&GroupedData[Source]=vs),GroupedData[Days],,1)))`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be with LAMBDA and SCAN.

```
=LET(filtered,FILTER($C$2:$D$24,($A$2:$A$24=H2)*($B$2:$B$24=I2)),
runningtotal,SCAN(0,CHOOSECOLS(filtered,2),LAMBDA(ini,arr,ini+arr)),
XLOOKUP(M2,runningtotal,CHOOSECOLS(filtered,1),,-1))
```

[image: Spill formula to lookup different sections of table based on two arguments]